# Sending messages to Azure Service Bus through Mass Transit

Tags: azure, servicebus, masstransit

i am using Premium version of Azure Service bus. in this paritioning is enabled by default. How do we set partition key when using Mass Trnasit on top of Azure Service Bus

Answer (score 1):

This is supported in the latest version of MassTransit. I'd highly recommend using the Gitter room for more real time conversations if you get stuck

http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/advanced/topology/servicebus/partitionkey.html

Here is an example from the documentation:

```
public interface SubmitOrder
{
    string CustomerId { get; }
    Guid TransactionId { get; }
    // ...
}

Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(..., cfg =>
{
    cfg.Send<SubmitOrder>(x =>
    {
        x.UsePartitionKeyFormatter(context => context.Message.CustomerId);
    });
});
```